# Android : Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Timed out waiting for the service connection

Tags: android, timeoutexception

I am getting this when I change the device's time, app stuck suddenly. App stuck or 2 to 5 minutes on device time change (More than 24 hrs.)

W/GoogleTagManager: IOException getting Ad Id Info
    java.io.IOException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Timed out waiting for the service connection
        at com.google.android.gms.ads.identifier.AdvertisingIdClient.zza(Unknown Source:26)
        at com.google.android.gms.ads.identifier.AdvertisingIdClient.zza(Unknown Source:28)
        at com.google.android.gms.ads.identifier.AdvertisingIdClient.getAdvertisingIdInfo(Unknown Source:51)
        at com.google.android.gms.tagmanager.zzb.zznj(Unknown Source:3)
        at com.google.android.gms.tagmanager.zza.zzni(Unknown Source:52)
        at com.google.android.gms.tagmanager.zza.zzb(Unknown Source:71)
        at com.google.android.gms.tagmanager.zzc.run(Unknown Source:2)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
     Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Timed out waiting for the service connection
        at com.google.android.gms.common.BlockingServiceConnection.getServiceWithTimeout(Unknown Source:13)
        at com.google.android.gms.ads.identifier.AdvertisingIdClient.zza(Unknown Source:4)
        at com.google.android.gms.ads.identifier.AdvertisingIdClient.zza(Unknown Source:28) 
        at com.google.android.gms.ads.identifier.AdvertisingIdClient.getAdvertisingIdInfo(Unknown Source:51) 
        at com.google.android.gms.tagmanager.zzb.zznj(Unknown Source:3) 
        at com.google.android.gms.tagmanager.zza.zzni(Unknown Source:52) 
        at com.google.android.gms.tagmanager.zza.zzb(Unknown Source:71) 
        at com.google.android.gms.tagmanager.zzc.run(Unknown Source:2) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)

Comment: Can you plz explain more that what you were trying to do?

Comment: Step-1 Open application and go to dashboard.
 Step-2 Open Setting of Android OS and Change Date (Example like more than 24 hrs). 
Step-3 Now come again on your app by swapping app (In this case your app will come foreground from background.)

Now you will observe the app has been stuck and you can not click anywhere and unable to use application.


Then getting those Lagcat errors...